# How to set value in scala Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am new to scala. I have a Map. I want to set a value in the Map with a particular key. Here is the code I am writing -

```
var mp: Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition] = Map.empty[Int, ParticipationStateTransition]

val change: ParticipationStateTransition = new ParticipationStateTransition

mp(ri.userID) = change
```

The error it is showing me on the third line is -

> application does not take parameters

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again... another pillar of functional programming is immutability. The map you created is immutable, you can not mutate it, but you can create another map with entries of this map and some extra. `mp = mp + ( ri.userId -> change )`

Comment: But please... read on how to use scala. -> http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/?_ga=1.228125279.336960921.1408827022 or https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/

Comment: if i write "mp = Map(ri.UserID -> change)" will it work? I need to add Maps in it quite a few times

Comment: Yes... it will, but it will assign `mp` to a new map containing only one entry.

Comment: @I.K. I am sorry if I have hurt your feelings. But I am really frustrated that is why I made the comment

Comment: @eddard.stark Scala is a language in `function paradigm`. Not every one has to like every paradigm. Yes it is different from `imperative paradigm` languages like Java etc. and needs more effort to learn, but the power that functional languages provide is kind of insane from the perspective of `imperative languages`. And you are frustrated because you are not putting any time in actually learning Scala, and are just trying stuff the same way as `imperative languages`. Its a paradigm shift similar to, Java ( OO ) vs C ( non-OO ). You will have to learn the new paradgim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `.updated` :

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> 2)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> val n = m.updated(1, 3)
n: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3)

scala> m
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> n
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3)
```

Note that scala's `Map` are immutable, so you need to assign the return value of `.updated`, it will not change the original map.

If you want to change the map in place, you can use `collection.mutable.Map` and then

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.Map(1 -> 2)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> m.update(1, 3)

scala> m
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3)
```

---

If you want to set multiple values at once, you can do :

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> 2)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> val n = m ++ List((1 -> 3), (2 -> 4)) // also accepts an Array, a Map, …
n: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 3, 2 -> 4)
```